# Applications for adaptive and non adaptive histogram equalization

Tags: equalization, histogram, adaptive-algorithms

I have a question regarding histogram equalization and adaptive histogram equalization.

In which circumstance would it be preferable to use adaptive histogram equalization over histogram equalization and similarly, when would it be preferable to use histogram equalization?

Which applications do they find more use in compared to one another?

From using Matlab, I understand the histogram equalization provides a uniform pixel region. And that adaptive histogram locally enhances the contrast on a specific pixel region.

Any thoughts? Thanks.